# JS not working properly

Tags: javascript

Following JS is not working properly:

```
document.getElementById("btn").value="harry";
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, false);
xmlhttp.send(null);
document.getElementById("btn").value="joy";
```

The default value of `btn` is `joy`. When I run this the value of `btn` is not changing. All other things are working fine.

***I want to see the value change to "harry" while ajax request is running.***

Why value is not changing? How to solve it?

HTML code:

```
<input id="btn" type="button" value="joy" onclick="change(id)" />
```

Comment: can you add your HTML here? Have you checked whether there is an element with an ID of 'id'?

Comment: Why do you expect it to change, where is the code that assigns value to "id"?

Comment: Off-topic: I'd *strongly* recommend against using the id `id`, though perhaps that's just paranoia on my part. I assume that's just an example.

Comment: Do you really need the xmlttp objects? They seem totally irrelevant for what you are doing at the moment..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The default value of id is joy. When I run this the value of id is not changing. All other things are working fine.

The end result of your code is to set the `value` property of the element `id` to "joy". You change it *temporarily* to "harry", but then almost immediately change it back to "joy".

If you're expecting to see the value change to "harry" while your synchronous ajax request is running, you're likely to be disappointed. Synchronous ajax requests completely lock up the UI of most browsers, preventing any changes you make from being displayed until the request completes — and of course, in your case, you're changing the value back to "joy" when that happens, so...

If you want to see "harry" while the request is running, make it asynchronous:

```
document.getElementById("id").value="harry";
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = handleReadyStateChange;
xmlhttp.send(null);
function handleReadyStateChange() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
        // Complete
        document.getElementById("id").value="joy";
    }
}
```

**Live examples**:

- [Synchronous version](http://jsbin.com/onibu4) (nothing shows during the request on most browsers)
- [Asynchronous version](http://jsbin.com/onibu4/2) (things get shown, because request is async)

Comment: @Harry: Good deal, glad that helped!

Comment: @Crowder "The default value of id is joy" kinda threw me off track :)

Comment: @Goran: changed `id` to `btn`.

Comment: @Harry: I'd actually recommend changing it back (perhaps just clarify that you're really using "id" as an `id` value); otherwise, my answer and a number of the comments read oddly.